# Power BI Lookup with Duplicates Equation

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]I have a data set that contains duplicates and i am trying to do the equivalent of a Vlookup from excel. In excel when you use the vlookup function it will just return the first value even if there is a duplicate. The data set that i am working with has a unique 16 character string.

I have utilized some videos, forms, and other resources but no luck. I have used the calculation equation with a first non blank and a filter but i either get an error or returns blank.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtrxZbQBYb0LjZtaIkZcn4qsMimwnQ?e=PZbNud

```
Column = CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('Table1'[ID]),
    FILTER('Table1','Table1'[Parent]='Table1'[ID]))
```

Comment: How do you decide which of the duplicates is "first"? What defines their order?

Comment: Time stamps, but from what i can see in all of the exports text 1 is the one I need to output. Just to the right of the text field is the time stamp (not visible in the image above).

Comment: You need to add the timestamps to your table, otherwise there is no way to determine what's "first". Also, please post your data sampe as text, so that people can prototype a solution.

Comment: I updated the post above where an excel file of the sample data can be found. Thanks for the help and looking at this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with:

```
Column = 
var SampleID = 'Sample Data'[ID]
var EarliestDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Sample Data'[Creation Date]);FILTER('Sample Data';'Sample Data'[Parent] = SampleID))
return CALCULATE(MIN('Sample Data'[Text]);FILTER('Sample Data';'Sample Data'[Parent] = SampleID && 'Sample Data'[Creation Date] = EarliestDate))
```

Note: it finds the earliest date ann when dates are equal, smallest string

Enjoy!